# icon panel widget used in google maps android ui

Tags: android, android-widget

Does anybody know the name of the widget that is used as the top icon-panel right under the notification bar in google maps on android? It's quite frequently used in 3rd party apps as well but i don't know how to google it and was unable to find it in the android standard widget gallery... To avoid confusion: in google maps ui on android it's the bar that contains the "search maps" textfield, the button that brings you to "find places" screen and the button that centers the map on your position. It's a gray horizontal bar with widgets separated by a thin black vertical line

Answer (score 0):

Ok found out already - it's called Action bar